# Using XOR Shift as a faster CRC32 checksum?

Tags: java, hash, checksum, crc32

Is it valid to use XOR shift to produce a usable checksum? I can't find any evidence that it collides more than say CRC32.

I did run a simulation on 10 million randomly generated 8 to 32 length byte arrays and the hash32 method below actually produced 2% less collisions than CRC32.

Also, the code seems to run about 40x faster than Java's built-in util.zip.CRC32 class.

```
public static long hash64( byte[] bytes )
    {
    long x = 1;
    for ( int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++ )
        {
        x ^= bytes[ i ];
        x ^= ( x << 21 );
        x ^= ( x >>> 35 );
        x ^= ( x << 4 );
        }

    return x;
    }


public static int hash32( byte[] bytes )
    {
    int x = 1;
    for ( int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++ )
        {
        x ^= bytes[ i ];
        x ^= ( x << 13 );
        x ^= ( x >>> 17 );
        x ^= ( x << 5 );
        }

    return x;
    }
```

Comment: ` x ^= ( x >>> 35 );` You *do* like arrows... What language is this?

Comment: Yes, I do like arrows.  It's Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if all you need is a simple file checksum, it's a completely valid alternative, but it's not the best solution.

CRCs are optimized for reliably detecting [burst errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burst_error), *not* collision resistance or uniform distribution. CRC-32 may superficially appear to work as a general hash function or a checksum, but [it readily fails avalanche and collision tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vm0Id.png), as you've seen in your test. CRC is also quite slow because it must implement polynomial division, which requires expensive operations, even when heavily optimized into shift operations. Table versions of CRC which utilize lookup tables (LUT) are also slow in interpreted languages such as Java due to unavoidable bounds-checking and conditional checks under the hood for each lookup.

Your solution is to take Xorshift, a pseudorandom function (PRF), and transform it into a hash function. On the surface, this may seem to pass basic collision tests, but it is not a very good choice. Its avalanche behavior is quite poor, and so there is a greater-than-chance probability of collisions that your tests aren't sensitive enough to find. Not only that, but it is sub-optimal, reading only one byte at a time. Better solutions exist with comparable performance.

A much better choice is [64-bit MurmurHash3](https://github.com/yonik/java_util/blob/master/src/util/hash/MurmurHash3.java), it performs quite well in Java when sufficiently optimized. It may even be faster than your solution for large inputs. I also recommend reading [Bret Mulvey's article on Hash Functions](https://papa.bretmulvey.com/post/124027987928/hash-functions). It explains how hash functions are constructed and tested in a digestible way.